# How do I change user interface language in Firefox to avoid so-called localization?

Tags: firefox

Since yesterday my Firefox thinks that everyone in Belgium speaks Flemish. This is a typically American problem: Americans NEVER seem to know where languages are spoken (I think they just guess), but for some reason believe that language localization software is cool.

It is NOT; it is a curse. So suddenly I no longer have my user interface in English (which was fine), but now in Flemish, which looks and reads like a tongue disease and is not even the second language of the area I live in (the first language here is German and second is French). How can I change back to English?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @grawity windows vista

Comment: Have you tried to install an English version from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html ?

Answer (score 3):

You should install an English language pack. A language pack is a Firefox add-on.

You can download it from [here](http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/win32/xpi/). Then you must install it like any other add-on ("install add-on from file" in the add-on interface).

Then you should change the language preference. You can do this by typing about:config in the Location bar (address bar) and then searching for

> general.useragent.locale

And change that to:

> en-US

(the same name as the downloaded .xpi)
Then you must restart the browser.

More details at:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Language_packs

Comment: I tried this solution in Firefox Quantum 60 (64 bit) on Windows 10, but didn't work. I could install the language page, but the "general.useragent.locale" key didn't show up in the about:config list. However, I could add the key manually with value "en-US", and that changed the UI language.

Answer (score 1):

Install en-US https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/english-us-language-pack/ and have key `intl.locale.requested` set to `en-US` in `about:config`.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-interface-other-languages-language-pack